# getting datetime when user logs-in

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

i made a django app which contains a user login form.
I have used MySQL database in the app. when the user logs-in an entry of name and Hashed Password  is created in the database. As of now i m trying, to get the datetime in the database when the user logs-In.

here's the code

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.core import validators
from first_app.models import Login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#some other code

class authForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:                                 
        model= Login
        fields = ["username","password",]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Login(models.Model):



    username = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    date_and_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)  #<-- tried to add but it shows a non editable field



    def __str__(self):                               
        return self.username
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import authForm
#from django.contrib.sessions import serializers

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        authform_data = authForm (request.POST or None)

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            authform_data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)
```

I want to store the datetime Everytime the user logs-In

thnx for the help. :-)

Comment: please share your view as well

Comment: anybody other answers for the specified qustion ?

Comment: Per our chat discussion, both answers are correct. Your problem is different and you need to create a separate questipn for that.

Comment: i think creating a new Question may not help as how can i raise problem which i m not aware of its just i want to add datetime to the database when the user logs-In :-/. also some information regarding that is :- **whenever some user logs-In a separate entry in database is created with username and password** hope u might find it relevent (if not please ignore)

Comment: Your new question should be about a case where your view function is now executed. Its a separate subject

Comment: after performing some debugging steps (like disabling the view function) i cannot authenticate the user .. though leading to the conclusion --> login_view is getting exceuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a login event model and create instance every time a user is logged-in. Here is an example:

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class LoginEvent(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_and_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class Login(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    date_and_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):                               
        return self.username
```

Then in your views:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import authForm
from .models import Login, LoginEvent


def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        authform_data = authForm(request.POST or None)

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            # here, create your event object
            login_event = LoginEvent.objects.create(user=user)
            authform_data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)
```

Comment: your code is helpful in the situations when there's a need to store **last_login** but i want to store datetime of each time the user logs-In. thnx for the reply.

Comment: whn running your code **python manage.py runserver** it shows **you have 3 migrations to apply** and then i m executing **python manage.py migrate** it says `OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'first_app_loginevent' already exists")` i tried with makemigrations but it says **no changes detected** again running your code **python manage.py runserver** it shows **you have 3 migrations to apply** . also in the database date-time doesn't appears. thnx for the reply. Please consider you code and make necessary changes. :-)

Comment: That is completely a different problem. You can migrate back and forth. Just go 3 migrations back by `python manage.py migrate 'your_3rd_previous_migration_name'`, then type `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: okay. ! tried that, error is solved but the database doesn't stores the login datetime yet :-/

Comment: nope.! no errors, application is working fine and so is the db but db does not displays user login datetime that i want to achieve.

Comment: You should look at the LoginEvent table. Can you make sure the `LoginEvent.objects.create(user=user)` is called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197481/discussion-between-mystery-and-cagrias).

Answer (score 0):

The built in `User` model has an attribute [`last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) that stores what you are asking for

Your custom user model doesn't seem to add any functionality that the built in user doesn't have, might be best to just use auth.User

EDIT:

To store every login time for every user would be best stored in it's own model

```
class UserLogin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

There is a signal sent every time a user logs in [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in), you can hook up this signal to a function that creates a `UserLogin` entry every time a user logs in

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def my_callback(sender, request=None, user=None):
    UserLogin.objects.create(user=user)
```

Now you will have a `UserLogin` object for every login for each user

Comment: does it store the datetime everytime the user logs-in or just the datetime of last login ?

Comment: The datetime of the last login

Comment: @lain please consider your code again as it shows the error **Signal receivers must accept keyword arguments (**kwargs)**